# Access ArangoDB data from client side

Tags: arangodb, foxx

I am new to ArangoDB, it is very nice that it can host micro-services directly in the database.

How would I go about sending queries / loading data directly from the client side (Jquery or Angular or whatever) across different domain names? assuming I have node on www.example.com (port 80) and would like to serve an application that (only) reads data directly from ArangoDB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm playing with Foxx/microservices too ... I wrote a little CRUD sample here : https://github.com/solisoft/arangodb-foxx-riotjs-sample

The live demo is here : http://foxx.solisoft.net

I use RiotJS/Foxx/jQuery/UIKit/Nginx

Comment: Pretty neat stuff. Have you tried connecting to Arango on a different domain name? I've read they support CORS, didn't try it though

Comment: Yes, and this is why I am mounting it in the same domain name ... I failed to make it work. :)

Comment: We have fixed an issue with CORS; The fix will be available with 3.0.4 next week. If you're keen on trying it out now, you need to compile arangodb from the 3.0 branch yourselves.

Comment: That is so cool Bart. Can you guys also publish some more example foxx plugins so people can have an easier time migrating. I know the REST API allows for basic functions but most people will want some business logic added on the database layer. Think of it as a marketing tool for your product. The easier you make it for people to get going with it, the faster it will be adopted. Look at Neo4J which is junk... they came such a long way thanks due to marketing.

Comment: 3.0.4 is available for download.